# How to create more Macros in C# Post build step

Tags: c#, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, post-build-event

I have an Visual Studio 2012 Solution that includes both C# and C++ projects.

I want to create a postbuild step and I notice that the C++ projects have much more macros than the C# projects.  I need to get the **WindowsSDKDir** which is available in the C++ macros but not in the C# macros.

**C++ Macros**
[image: Macros available for C++ Projects]

**C# Macros**

[image]

Can I see all the Macros that are available to the C++ projects in the C# projects??

Answer (score 1):

I can think about the following workaround. Write this post-build command:

```
$(ProjectDir)post_build.bat
```

Create `post_build.bat` file in the project directory and fill it by this way:

```
echo %WindowsSdkDir%
echo %WinDir%
```

Build the project, it prints:

```
ECHO is on.
C:\Windows
```

So, C# is not smart enough to see Visual Studio build environment variables (`%WindowsSdkDir%` is expanded to nothing), but at least general environment variable like `WinDir` is expanded. So, you can create your own environment variable with the same value as `WindowsSDKDir` and use it in batch file called from Post-Build step.

To make something more useful then `echo`, create batch file with parameters (`%1%`, `%2%` etc.) and call it from post-build step, passing required parameters. For example:

```
$(ProjectDir)post_build.bat $(TargetPath)
```

In the batch file `%1%` will be expanded as output file name.

Answer (score 0):

Simply call the batch file that sets up environment variables for a Visual Studio command prompt as the first line of your build event. This will set up all the environment variables for use in later lines of your build event. For example...

```
call "$(DevEnvDir)..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
"%WindowsSdkDir%bin\x86\rc.exe" <parameters>
```

Note that the environment variables are Windows environment variables and need to be accessed via the %VAR_NAME% syntax rather than the $(VAR_NAME) syntax.

The location of the vcvarsall.bat file is consistent over at least VS2012, 2013 and 2015, meaning that this solution is generic and doesn't need tweaking for different VS versions.

If you use msbuild you will find that $(DevEnvDir) is not set correctly when building in msbuild. In that case, this alternative should work for both msbuild and visual studio build providing you have not customized the visual studio install location.

```
call "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio $(VisualStudioVersion)\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
```